# Technologies needed to build a video-heavy site

Tags: video-streaming, web-hosting

This is a newbie question, but I would like to know what are the technologies needed to build a video-heavy website in terms of hosting, delivery (i.e., CDN), compression and display?

My site will have a few thousand short clips (1-5 minutes), but it will be accessed from various countries. Users will only view videos uploaded by staff. (I will use Ruby on Rails for front-end-if this matters)

Thank you.

Comment: just out of curiosity why not allow youtube to do the hosting?

Comment: Hi, the reason is quite specific to the business model and how I charge my clients. I don't know if Youtube has hosting option for business (white-label).

Comment: you can definitely make the videos private